# Passenger on EasyApache 4/CentOS/cPanel will not start Rails app

Tags: passenger

On a new server, CentOS/EasyApache 4, I created a single account and set up a new Rails 6.0.2 app. I first installed Passenger 6.0.4 using the EasyApache interface and was unable to start the Rails app.

`Web application could not be started by the Phusion Passenger application server`

But there was no error mentioned in the Apache error log. (And nothing in the Rails log since it didn't start.) I increased the log level but still nothing I could identify. Certainly no error that matches the error ID shown on the page.

I removed that version of Passenger and instead installed it as a gem -- I first tried installing as my app user but got "not secure" permissions errors on the application directories -- so I installed RVM and Passenger as root user.

Each time, no matter how I install, I still get the same error screen but no error in the logs. Passenger seems to be running, it seems to be playing nice with Apache. I can launch the Rails app in console in production, and I can make database calls.

Not sure where to go to look for details. Below is the Apache error log, starting with the last time I rebooted Apache. Not sure if Passenger is starting up, shutting down and starting again? I've never had to look before, so I don't know if this is normal. But in the end, it looks to be running. And there is no error registered after this, even though I've hit the site several times and gotten error screens. Thanks for any help.

```
[Fri May 01 14:07:43.442039 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 12050] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4543 12056/T8 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:671 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4543 12056/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1246 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4544 12056/T8 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4545 12056/T8 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4546 12056/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4546 12056/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4547 12056/T9 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.4547 12056/T9 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:43.9554 12056/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.0784 18605/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.0950 18608/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.0951 18608/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1015 18608/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 18608
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.102969 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity for Apache/2.9.3 (http://www.modsecurity.org/) configured.
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.103122 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity: APR compiled version="1.7.0"; loaded version="1.7.0"
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.103127 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity: PCRE compiled version="8.32 "; loaded version="8.32 2012-11-30"
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.103129 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity: LUA compiled version="Lua 5.1"
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.103131 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity: YAJL compiled version="2.0.4"
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.103133 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity: LIBXML compiled version="2.9.7"
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.103141 2020] [:notice] [pid 18603] ModSecurity: Status engine is currently disabled, enable it by set SecStatusEngine to On.

[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1052 18608/T8 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:671 ]: Signal received. Gracefully shutting down... (send signal 2 more time(s) to force shutdown)
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1052 18608/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1246 ]: Received command to shutdown gracefully. Waiting until all clients have disconnected...
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1053 18608/Tb Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.2] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1053 18608/Tb Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.2] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1053 18608/T8 Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ServerThr.1] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1053 18608/T8 Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ServerThr.1] Shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1054 18608/Tc Ser/Server.h:902 ]: [ApiServer] Freed 0 spare client objects
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1054 18608/Tc Ser/Server.h:558 ]: [ApiServer] Shutdown finished
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.130060 2020] [:notice] [pid 18628] mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1508 18631/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1733 18634/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1735 18634/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.1800 18634/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 18634
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.184432 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18628] AH00163: Apache/2.4.43 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.1.1g mod_bwlimited/1.4 Phusion_Passenger/6.0.4 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri May 01 14:07:44.184457 2020] [core:notice] [pid 18628] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd'
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.6441 18608/T1 age/Cor/TelemetryCollector.h:531 ]: Message from Phusion: End time can not be before or equal to begin time
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:44.6750 18608/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1325 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
[ N 2020-05-01 14:07:46.7458 18634/T4 age/Cor/SecurityUpdateChecker.h:519 ]: Security update check: no update found (next check in 24 hours)
```

Comment: Hey,
Did you had a look into your application `log/production.log` file? By default Passenger is using production environment and you might have to do some extra things (like creating a database or compiling your assets) before successfully running your rails application.
As far as I remember, lunching twice is a normal behaviour for passenger. I recall some blog article about this on fusion website.

Comment: Yep, looked there, and nothing. I finally bailed on this and went with a different host without EasyApache. Thanks.